# QTableView() only updates changes when selected

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have inserted data into the subclassed `QAbstractListModel` and displayed it with a `QListView` and `QTableView`

changes (deleating a row) are displayed in the `QListView` imidiatly but in the `QTableView` only if the table view is selected

the sublcassed model contains the `setData` method with `self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)` inside so it should update itself.

why does the `QTableView does not update itself right away ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
minimum code to run a model view

"""



import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg


class ViewModel(qtc.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, input_data=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_data = input_data or []




    # naming of rows ,columns static !!
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == qtc.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == qtc.Qt.Horizontal:


                return "dude" # todo dynamic labeling
            else:

                return "leboswki"  # todo dynamic labeling



    def data(self, index, role):

        if role == qtc.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row() # == wie liste[row] der index

            item = self.input_data[row]
            return item




    def rowCount(self, index): # parameter inside is needed !

        return len(self.input_data)



    def flags(self, index):
        return qtc.Qt.ItemIsEditable | qtc.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | qtc.Qt.ItemIsEnabled



    def setData(self, index, value, role):

        if role == qtc.Qt.EditRole:
            row = index.row()
            if index.isValid():
                self.input_data[row] = value
                self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
                return True
            else:
                return False


    def removeRows(self, position, rows, parent=qtc.QModelIndex()):
        self.beginRemoveRows(parent, position, position + rows-1)

        for i in range(rows):
            value = self.input_data[position]
            self.input_data.remove(value)

        self.endRemoveRows()
        return True





class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # View
        list_view = qtw.QListView()
        self.model = ViewModel(input_data=["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4"])
        list_view.setModel(self.model)


        table_view = qtw.QTableView()
        table_view.setModel(self.model)


        # widgets
        self.deleate_row_button = qtw.QPushButton("deleate rows")

        # layout
        qvboxlayout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        qvboxlayout.addWidget(list_view)
        qvboxlayout.addWidget(table_view)
        qvboxlayout.addWidget(self.deleate_row_button)
        self.setLayout(qvboxlayout)
        self.show()

        # function
        self.deleate_row_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.model.removeRows(-1, 1))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although in Python you can access negative indexes but that does not happen in Qt causing the error. The solution is to convert the negative indices to positive. On the other hand, do not delete the rows by their value (`self.input_data.remove(value)`) since if it had 2 rows with the same text, there could be an error.

```
def rowCount(self, index=qtc.QModelIndex()):
    return 0 if index.isValid() else len(self.input_data)
```

```
def removeRows(self, position, rows, parent=qtc.QModelIndex()):
    position = (position + self.rowCount()) if position < 0 else position
    start = position
    end = position + rows - 1
    self.beginRemoveRows(parent, start, end)
    del self.input_data[start : end + 1]
    self.endRemoveRows()
    return True
```